# Should wordpress_logged_in cookie exist while logged out?

Tags: cookies, authentication

I noticed that while logged out on my Wordpress site, my browser is sending this `Cookie` header with every request (obfuscated for security):

> ```
> Cookie: wordpress_logged_in_OBFUSCATED=flimm%7COBFUSCATED; PHPSESSID=OBFUSCATED; wordpress_logged_in_OBFUSCATED=flimm%7COBFUSCATED;wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check
> ```

For readability, here are the cookies in separate lines:

- `wordpress_logged_in_OBFUSCATED=flimm%7COBFUSCATED`
- `PHPSESSID=OBFUSCATED`
- `wordpress_logged_in_OBFUSCATED=flimm%7COBFUSCATED`
- `wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check`

Is this normal, that even though I am logged out, I still have a cookie set `wordpress_logged_in_...`, with my old username in it?

Is it normal to have more than one `wordpress_logged_in_...` cookie set, whether logged in or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `wp_logout` (https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L564) calls the function `wp_clear_auth_cookie` (https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L928) which sets the expiration dates of all involved cookies to something in the past. Also for the `LOGGED_IN_COOKIE`.

Hence, what you observe is strange. For sites that I maintain, the cookie will be cleared when I log out.

Comment: That's what I thought. Is it also weird that more than one `wordpress_logged_in_...` cookie has been set?

Comment: I get two `wordpress_logged_in_...` cookies when `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` differ. However, both are deleted when I log out.